# git: how to cherry-pick and overwrite remote

Tags: git

How do I pull only some files from the latest remote commit, and then push to overwrite all remote files with my local files?

I tried

```
git fetch
git checkout file1
git push
```

I got "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the push by using `git push --force`. This will force your current state to the remote branch (which could mess other people up, btw).

Comment: Furthermore, anyone else using this branch will have to delete their branch and re-fetch it. `git push --force` will make you very unpopular, and the changes you override are *not* recoverable. In many cases you may want to make a new commit with the files you don't changed *reverted*, and the relevant file re-committed, so that in a years' time you'll know what theell happened here! :)